# sqlalchemy: Группировка данных внутри сгруппированных данных

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Имеется `sqlalchemy`:

```py
class EventLog(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    subject = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
```

Имеется таблица с данными:

```
| id | subject | created_at |
| -- | ------_ | ---------- |
| 1  | CarOffer| 2023-04-11 |
| 2  | CarOffer| 2023-04-12 |
| 3  | CarOffer| 2023-04-13 |
| 4  | Drivers | 2023-04-11 |
| 5  | Drivers | 2023-04-11 |
| 6  | Drivers | 2023-04-12 |
```

Нужно с помощью `sqlalchemy` выполнить запрос так, чтобы полученные данные были в формате:

Объект: число созданных объектов по дням.

Например:

> CarOffer: `[{"2023-04-11": 1}, {"2023-04-12": 1}, {"2023-04-13": 1}]`

> Drivers:  `[{"2023-04-11": 2}, {"2023-04-12": 1}, {"2023-04-13": 0}]`

В идеале, чтобы при этом не отображались даты.

> CarOffer: `[1, 1, 1]`

> Drivers: `[2, 1, 0]`